# How does this call to a subroutine in a Perl module work?

Tags: perl, perl-module

I recently saw some Perl code that confused me.  I took out all of the extra parts to see how it was working, but I still don't understand why it works.

Basically, I created this dummy "module" (TTT.pm):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package TTT;
sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    return bless {'Test' => 'Test'}, $class;
}

sub acquire {
    my $tt = new TTT();
    return $tt;
}
1;
```

Then I created this script to use the module (ttt.pl):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use TTT;
our $VERSION = 1;

my $tt = acquire TTT;
print $tt->{Test};
```

The line that confuses me, that I thought would not work, is:

```
my $tt = acquire TTT;
```

I thought it would not work since the "acquire" sub was never exported.  But it does work.
I was confused by the "TTT" after the call to acquire, so I removed that, leaving the line like this:

```
my $tt = acquire;
```

And it complained of a bareword, like I thought it would.  I added parens, like this:

```
my $tt = acquire();
```

And it complained that there wasn't a `main::acquire`, like I thought it would.

I'm used to the subroutines being available to the object, or subroutines being exported, but I've never seen a subroutine get called with the package name on the end.  I don't even know how to search for this on Google.

So my question is, How does adding the package name after the subroutine call work?  I've never seen anything like that before, and it probably isn't good practice, but can someone explain what Perl is doing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are using the indirect object syntax that Perl allows (but in modern code is discouraged).  Basically, if a name is not predeclared, it can be placed in front of an object (or class name) separated with a space.

So the line `acquire TTT` actually means `TTT->acquire`.  If you actually had a subroutine named `acquire` in scope, it would instead be interpreted as `aquire(TTT)` which is can lead to ambiguity (hence why it is discouraged).

You should also update the `new TTT();` line in the method to read `TTT->new;`

Comment: Thanks so much - it makes total sense now!

Answer (score 6):

It's the [indirect object syntax](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlobj#Indirect_Object_Syntax___) for method calls, which lets you put the method name *before* the object name.

As the documentation there shows, it's best avoided because it's unwieldy and it can break in unpredictable ways, for example if there *is* an imported or defined subroutine named `acquire` — but it used to be more common than it is today, and so you will find it pretty often in old code and docs.

Comment: The somewhat-still-sanctioned use of this syntax is with a package's `new` method, so you can say `$obj = new Object` rather than `$obj = Object::new`. This helps the C++ programmers to think that they know what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @hobbs - that makes a lot of sense now!

Comment: @mob: I assume that by "somewhat" you mean "people will grumble but probably won't break your kneecaps." Too many people think that the `new` in `new Object` is a keyword when it's just a convention.

Comment: @mob Most perlers (I know) deprecate indirect calls--even for `new`. I would recommend that indirect calls be eschewed uniformly, except in DSLs which work best that way.

Comment: There are certainly disadvantages to calling `new Object`. But getting C++ programmers into the fold is one possible advantage of it (whether it is Good to use the language first and learn how to use it second is beyond the scope of this discussion, so I'll use the weasel word 'possible').